# Ошибка подключения к веб ресурсу Android

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Всем здравия!

Я для личного развития, да и восстановления знаний, вернулся к Android Studio (v3.6.1 так как новые версии идут под 64х системы). И тут такая ситуация: при попытке подключиться к сайту возвращается такая ошибка.

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.pastebinparser, PID: 13162
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4791)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4791) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697) 
 Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
    at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:199)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
    at com.example.pastebinparser.MainActivity.onButtonClick(MainActivity.java:42)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4791) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

Как я понял из-за этого типа ошибки (`java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`) прекращается работа приложения.

Цель приложения: прочесть сайт, получить его HTML и парсить его.

Так же для этих целей была импортирована библиотека Jsoup, но она так же возвращает `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` при вызове

```
Jsoup.connect("https://pastebin.com/1HhJHSec").get()
```

Код моего приложения:

```
package com.example.pastebinparser;

import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  AnimationDrawable mAnimation;   // анимация
  ImageView mImageView;           // анимируемый объект
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // =====================================================
    // Подготовка к анимации объекта
    // =====================================================
    mImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);
    mAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) mImageView.getBackground();
    // =====================================================
    // Конец подготовки к анимации объекта
    // =====================================================
  }
  public void onButtonClick(View view) {

    mAnimation.start(); //запустить анимацию

    // =====================================================
    // Подключение к сайту
    // =====================================================
    String adress ="https://pastebin.com/1HhJHSec";
    Document doc = null;
    try {
      URL url = new URL(adress);
      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));// эта строка вызывает ошибку
      String line = null;
      String result = "";
      while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result += line;
      }
      EditText et = findViewById(R.id.editText);
      et.setText(result);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("lol");
    }
    // =====================================================
    // Конец подключения к сайту
    // =====================================================
  }
}
```

P.S. Проверял наличие интернета и доступ на ресурс с телефона. Интернет имеется, ресурс не заблокирован.

Comment: У вас NetworkOnMainThreadException - вам надо запрос в сеть вынести в другой поток. Способов много, правильных нет, есть предпочитаемые, есть простые, есть с множеством возможностей. Если хотите хардкора - используйте RxJava, если олдСкула - AsyncTask. Если чего-то примитивного - берите Thread.

Comment: Знаешь? Мне сейчас обидно. Я написал сотню строк и из них парочка - подключение к сайту. Андроид студио получает эту ошибку "Использование сети в основном потоке". А сейчас я открыл игровой движок Godot Engine, написал 2 строки для ноды HTTPRequest и она без ошибок прочитала структуру сайта.

Comment: Всё в программировании - набор условностей, компромисов и прочего. В андроиде решили, что программист сам может управлять потоками. В iOS, например, указать в каком потоке делать запрос в сеть - нельзя. В андроиде выносить вручную в другой поток да, надо. Как какой-то там движок это делает - надо смотреть. Он может делать лютую дичь, которую потом сложно править/кастомизировать. В общем, не стоит так уж с ходу ругать то, как оно в андроиде сделано) Альтернативы могут оказаться гораздо хуже)